# Create binary tree from a list in java

Tags: java, list, binary-tree

I'm trying to make a binary tree based on a list. The list contains on index 0 the node, and on the index 1 and 2, the left and right child. On index 3 is another node and on index 4 and 5 is left and right child for the node on index 3, and so on. I've tried something like this

```
public static HNode buildHTree(List<HNode> list) {
        HNode node = lista.get(0);
        HNode left = lista.get(1);
        HNode right = lista.get(2);
        list.remove(0);
        list.remove(0);
        list.remove(0);
        if(list.size() > 0)
            return buildHTree(list);
        return node;
    }
```

but this doesn't work. Can some of you give me some hint or some help in making this.
The HNode class contains:

```
private Symbol value;
private HNode left, right;
```

and setters and getters for this.
Thank you very much

Comment: *but this doesn't work* is not a problem description. Do you want our sympathy or our assistance?

Comment: I want to tell me what is wrong with my thinking and how can change my code to achieve my goal.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you are asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Are you trying to build *one* binary tree from the list? From your description of what is in the list, it sounds like data for a whole forest. If the list contains, say, 15 elements, that should suffice for 5 trees, not just 1 tree, if I understand your description right?

Comment: It may be clear in your head, but after reading your question a couple of times it isn’t in mine. If we’re t help, please be more specific about the desired behaviour of your program. I think an example with a list of 6 elements and the expected resulting tree/s will help very well.

Comment: `lista` the same as `list`? and missing something like `node.setLeft(...)`, that is, the variables `left` and `right`are not being used at all,

Answer (score 2):

> I want to tell me what is wrong with my thinking and how can change my code to achieve my goal.

One thing that is wrong with your thinking is that you seem to think that you can write "some code" and then "change" it to make it right.  That is not a good way to program.

The better / right way is to:

1. understand the requirements before you start designing,
2. understand the algorithm before you start coding it,
3. when you run into a problem, read the code you have written and **try to understand** what it actually does.  Then compare that with what you are trying to achieve; i.e. what you *intended* to write.

And don't be afraid of throwing away stuff and starting again.

---

Specific hints:

1. Should you be starting from a `List<HNode>`?  Shouldn't it really be a `List<Symbol>`?
2. Shouldn't you be setting the left / right fields to put the nodes into a tree structure?
3. Do you know if the list is sorted?